# Group by and save the max value with overlapping columns in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data that looks like this:

```text
id,start,expiration,customerid,content
1,13494,17358,0001,whateveriwanthere
2,14830,28432,0001,somethingelsewoo
3,11943,19435,0001,yes
4,39271,40231,0002,makingfakedata
5,01321,02143,0002,morefakedata
```

In the data above, I want to group by `customerid` for overlapping `start` and `expiration` (essentially just merge intervals). I am doing this successfully by grouping by the customer id, then aggregating on a `first("start")` and `max("expiration")`.

```scala
df.groupBy("customerid").agg(first("start"), max("expiration"))
```

**However, this drops the `id` column entirely**. I want to save the `id` of the row that had the max expiration. For instance, I want my output to look like this:

```text
id,start,expiration,customerid
2,11934,28432,0001
4,39271,40231,0002
5,01321,02143,0002
```

I am not sure how to add that `id` column for whichever row had the maximum expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cumulative conditional sum along with `lag` function to define `group` column that flags rows that overlap. Then, simply group by `customerid` + `group` and get min `start` and max `expiration`. To get the `id` value associated with max expiration date, you can use this trick with struct ordering:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("customerid").orderBy("start")

val result = df.withColumn(
    "group",
    sum(
      when(
        col("start").between(lag("start", 1).over(w), lag("expiration", 1).over(w)),
        0
      ).otherwise(1)
    ).over(w)
).groupBy("customerid", "group").agg(
    min(col("start")).as("start"),
    max(struct(col("expiration"), col("id"))).as("max")
).select("max.id", "customerid", "start", "max.expiration")

result.show
//+---+----------+-----+----------+
//| id|customerid|start|expiration|
//+---+----------+-----+----------+
//|  5|      0002|01321|     02143|
//|  4|      0002|39271|     40231|
//|  2|      0001|11943|     28432|
//+---+----------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! Amazing job dude.